# Make Array Contiguous Subsequence By Adding Digits

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, algorithm

Suppose i have a series of elements in array as [2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]. I can add any number digit before or after or in middle of number in array such that the array become contiguous and return the smallest minimum element. for above array we can make it as [21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30] and min element is 21.
Number will always be positive, not negative numbers and floats will be there in array.

Another example - [6 7 8 9 4 4 2 3]
Answer - [36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43] Min - 36

Comment: Can you explain your algorithm

Comment: @Sujay Are U Asking my approach or about Question? if ur asking my approach what i thought was if 2 consecutive elements are same like in 2nd example ill take value less than that in above case 4 is conecutive 2 times so i took 3. I'm new to coding and still learning so no idea beyind this and struck

Comment: @PrantaPalit. I think it's because there are 2 consecutive 2. So the base number is 2.

Comment: @Corralien yeah I found it, but why not `[02,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]`?

Comment: @PrantaPalit for given elements in array u have to add a digit before or after to make it contiguous sequnce.  For ```[2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]``` Answer will be ```[21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30]`` coz for each element we are adding a digit before or after to make contiguous. ```[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]``` this wont come coz first element given is 2 but its not there in ur 1st elemet. i dont have solution what i thought was f 2 consecutive elements are same like in 2nd example ill take value less than that in above case 4 is conecutive 2 times so i took 3.but this wont hold for all

Comment: @Noob is it okay to make `[02,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]`?

Comment: @PrantaPalit: No. 02 is 10 places away from the contiguous block formed by the other numbers, so the result isn't contiguous. (I'm not sure you can prepend a redundant zero, either.)

Comment: @MOehm Yes!! It SHould be contiguous

Comment: Are the given numbers already in the correct order, so that the contiguous array is strictly increasing?

Comment: @MOehm Yes.. It'll be in order.. it may be any no of digit... in the example its a single digit.. we cand add 3 or 4 digits too

Comment: @Noob, do you want contiguous and consecutive? if not, for array [2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0], can we make [20 21 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30]?

Comment: The problem cannot be solved without adding some constraints and relaxing others. 
For instance, the mini array [5, 3] can be made continuous in more than 1 way, for example as [52, 53] and as [35, 36]. Some minimality constraint is needed. Also, some sequences have no solution unless the "inserting a digit" is changed into "inserting any number of digits". Consider for example [123, 5]. A solution like [1234,1235] is currently invalid, since it needs 3 digit-insertions per number. The problem talks about arrays of "elements", but I doubt inputs with negative numbers, floats are allowed.

Comment: @KoenAIS The First Element should be min... in that case 35 is less than 52 so we take ```[35 36]``` No Negative inputs and floats

Comment: @KoenAIS For [123,5] U can add any no of digits. it should be contigous and minimum as i said in above comment

Comment: You have posted an ambiguous question w/o much explanation about the algorithm first.  So what's your first thought and where do you want others to help?

Comment: Please update your problem description. It says "a digit", not "any number of digits". It says "return the minimum element (of the resulting array)", not "return the smallest minimum element that is possible" It talks about "(any) elements", while your comments suddenly change that to "non-negative integers". I'm am sorry about my type in "continuous", especially so because the contiguous property was & is the only one that is clear from the current description. I've solved it in the mean-time. I'll post it if you clean up your description.

Comment: @KoenAIS I've Edited question can u tell me how to approach that ??

Comment: Your edit is not perfect but I appreciate the effort and I'll stick by my word. I need some time to clean up the thing I hacked together. I'll post an answer in about an hour.

Comment: @KoenAIS Sure... Thank For Help

Comment: My approach is to fix any pair [a,b] that is not contiguous by modifying a and b into a' and b' such that b'-a'=1. For the required modification I just do a brute (recursive) minimization search based on the subtraction algorithm (still linear). Unfortunately, I noticed an annoying bug while composing the answer which I couldn't solve within the deadline I set myself and it's getting late. I'm quite annoyed about that and it has become a matter of principle to give a proper answer, but it'll have to be delayed until the morning. Perhaps the hint about the approach helps somewhat until then.

Comment: @KoenAIS I'll Try that.... Send ur version of code whenever ur free and got it.. Thanks!!

Comment: The bug I couldn't solve yesterday turned out to a dumb one and the fix was plainly obvious this morning. I've posted the code in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a solution. It's not thoroughly tested, but it does what it is supposed to do for the examples given in the problem statement.

```
test(new int[]{2 ,2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,0});
// output: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], min = 21
test(new int[]{6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 4, 2, 3}); 
// output: [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43], min = 36
```

It's in Java, but it shouldn't be hard to convert to another language of choice.

Here's the test method:

```
public void test(int[] arr)
{
    int min = modifyAndMinimize(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) + ", min = " + min);
}
```

Array modifier:

```
/**
 * Modifies the numbers (which must be non-negative) in arr such that the new version
 * is contiguous, meaning that for every subsequence [u, v], v - u = 1.
 * The only type of modification that is applied is to insert digits into the elements of arr.
 * This can be done in many ways, but this function chooses the way that results in
 * the smallest possible first element (which this function returns).
 */
public int modifyAndMinimize(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int u = arr[i], v = arr[i + 1];
        int minU = modifyAndMinimize(3, u, v, "", "", 1); // hardcoded 3 out of laziness, but it's really a function of the number of digits of u and v
        if (v != minU + 1)
            arr[i + 1] = minU+ 1;
        if (u != minU) {
            arr[i] = minU;
            i = -1; // lazy way of moving back to fix the previous numbers
        }
    }
    return arr[0];
}
```

Now the crux, i.e. the function that "fixes" two consecutive elements (the idea is simple, but it's tricky to implement and impossible to debug late at night as I found out yesterday):

```
/** 
 * Finds the smallest u' and v' such that v' - u' = diff, where u' and v' are modified versions
 * of u and v obtained by inserting digits.
 *
 * The approach is essentially the common subtraction algorithm, but instead of computing the
 * result of v - u, it's given the result and asked to compute u' and v' such that v' - u'
 * is the result (diff).
 */
public int modifyAndMinimize(int maxDepth, int u, int v, String doneU, String doneV, int diff) {
    if (maxDepth < 0) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    // if v - u == diff, we're done
    if (v - u == diff)
        return Integer.parseInt(u + doneU);

    // v and/or u need to be modified, but perhaps their last digits are already ok
    if ((v - u - diff) % 10 == 0)
        return modifyAndMinimize(maxDepth - 1, u / 10, v / 10, u % 10 + doneU, (v % 10) + doneV, diff / 10);

    // they're not ok. To fix this, try appending the appropriate digit to u and try appending
    // the appropriate digit to v. Choose the option that results in the smallest modified u.

    int appendToU = v % 10 - diff;
    int carry = appendToU / 10;
    appendToU %= 10;
    if (appendToU < 0) {
        appendToU += 10;
        carry--;
    }
    int option1 = modifyAndMinimize(maxDepth - 1, u, v / 10, appendToU + doneU, (v % 10) + doneV, diff / 10 - carry);

    int appendToV = u % 10 + diff;
    carry = appendToV / 10;
    appendToV %= 10;
    if (appendToV < 0) {
        appendToV += 10;
        carry--;
    }
    int option2 = modifyAndMinimize(maxDepth - 1, u / 10, v, (u % 10) + doneU, appendToV + doneV, diff / 10 + carry);

    return Math.min(option1, option2);
}
```

It's very well possible there's a much nicer approach than to use brute force to decide whether a digit should be added to either u or v (it's exponential in the number of digits, so it's linear in the numbers themselves). If so, I missed it.